# Developing a record and playback tool using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to develop a record and playback tool using selenium webdriver like the way Selenium IDE does. I started withCchrome browser, tried different approaches. Few of them are here:

1. Tried creating a JavaScript with event listeners and tried executing it using JavascriptExecutor. In the JS script I have implicit wait to return some value. Sample code:

   ```
   var flag = 0;
   var elementId;    
   window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {         
       elementTagName=e.target.id;
       alert(elementTagName);   
       flag++;
   });

   var timer = setInterval(function () {
       myTimer();
   }, 1000);

   function myTimer() {    
       if(flag == 0){
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=flag;
       } else {
           clearInterval(timer);
           return elementId; //Returning the element ID which was clicked
       }
   }
   ```

But now the problem is, webdriver code written in java(shown below) is not waiting for the return. Same code works fine when I run it individually.

```
Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
if (null != response) {
    System.out.println((String) response);
}
```

Any other way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the JS value, you can store it in a JS variable, by changing this line:

```
return elementId;
```

to this:

```
retVal = elementId;
```

Then, whenever you would have accessed `response` in Java, execute JS to access the JS var on the page instead:

```
// execute JS functions from your question above
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);

// wait however long needed for those functions to complete
Thread.sleep(1000);

// get result from page
String response = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return retVal");
```